# List of numpy arrays to one numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say I have N numpy arrays, each of size (x, y, z), where y and z are the same for all but x differs for each. How would I combine these to a numpy array of size (w, y, z) where w is the sum of all x.

Or, for a numerical example: I have a list of 3 numpy array with sizes (14, 32, 32), (7, 32, 32), (50, 32, 32). How do I turn these into a (71, 32, 32) sized numpy array efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just concatenate them along the first axis. If your 3 numpy arrays are named x1, x2, and x3, your new array would be defined as `x_combined = np.concatenate((x1,x2,x3),axis=0)`

Comment: I have tried this already, but I get the error that the input arrays have to have the same dimensions. It may be the way my list of arrays is constructed, so I will double check that.

Comment: It was the data. I am working with images, and for some reason one set had not loaded so it had a shape of (0,).

Comment: If the other dimensions are the same, this method should work with no problem. For the axis you are concatenating along, the input arrays can have any length as long as the others are identical in length.

Comment: I removed that set of images (which for some reason does not load) and the issue was resolved. I had thought it was the way I was doing it as I had tried both of these suggestions already and they did not work because of that.

Answer (score 2):

Try `np.vstack`

```
a, b , c = np.ones((14, 32, 32)), np.ones((7, 32, 32)), np.ones((50, 32, 32))

out = np.vstack([a,b,c])

In [119]: a.shape
Out[119]: (14, 32, 32)

In [120]: b.shape
Out[120]: (7, 32, 32)

In [121]: c.shape
Out[121]: (50, 32, 32)

In [122]: out.shape
Out[122]: (71, 32, 32)
```

Comment: I have tried this already, but I get the error that the input arrays have to have the same dimensions. It may be the way my list of arrays is constructed, so I will double check that.

Comment: double check with the `shape` command as in my answer. That error indicates one of your array doesn't match on both `w, z` dimension.

Comment: It was the data. I am working with images, and for some reason one set had not loaded so it had a shape of (0,).